# threejs rotate the object gradually to where camera is looking using orbit control

Tags: three.js

I'm planning to use Orbit Control to do a simple 3rd person camera view,
But I cant seem to figure out how to do it.
when I rotate the camera around an object, and press say “W” key to move forward, I want the object “look” to gradually rotate and move to the new direction the camera is facing.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do exactly that by gradually rotating the object to the camera direction.
Made a codepen here which uses a generic replacement to orbit controls for simplicity:
https://codepen.io/cdeep/pen/QWMWyYW

```js
    // Get the X-Z plane in which camera is looking to move the player
    camera.getWorldDirection(tempCameraVector);
    const cameraDirection = tempCameraVector.setY(0).normalize();
    
    // Get the X-Z plane in which player is looking to compare with camera
    model.getWorldDirection(tempModelVector);
    const playerDirection = tempModelVector.setY(0).normalize();

    // Get the angle to x-axis. z component is used to compare if the angle is clockwise or anticlockwise since angleTo returns a positive value
    const cameraAngle = cameraDirection.angleTo(xAxis) * (cameraDirection.z > 0 ? 1 : -1);
    const playerAngle = playerDirection.angleTo(xAxis) * (playerDirection.z > 0 ? 1 : -1);
    
    // Get the angle to rotate the player to face the camera. Clockwise positive
    const angleToRotate = playerAngle - cameraAngle;
    
    // Get the shortest angle from clockwise angle to ensure the player always rotates the shortest angle
    let sanitisedAngle = angleToRotate;
    if(angleToRotate > Math.PI) {
      sanitisedAngle = angleToRotate - 2 * Math.PI
    }
    if(angleToRotate < -Math.PI) {
      sanitisedAngle = angleToRotate + 2 * Math.PI
    }
    
    // Rotate the model by a tiny value towards the camera direction
    model.rotateY(
      Math.max(-0.05, Math.min(sanitisedAngle, 0.05))
    );
```